# Issue with extracting text from text box in word document using python-docx

Tags: python, textbox, python-docx

I want to extract the text inside a text box using python-docx. I've tried with the paragraphs and tables attributes, but I couldn't extract the text. Please let me know if it is possible to extract the text by using python-docx or should I try with other libraries.

This is the link to the file:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_metGi8aqPn8XciyjpbONOq4XdTNeuDD/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=104132986734597597850&rtpof=true&sd=true

Here is the code snippet using the paragraphs attribute:

```
!pip install python-docx
import docx

source_file = 'textbox.docx'
doc = docx.Document(source_file)

text = [];
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    text.append(para.text)
text
```

Here is the code snippet using the tables attribute:

```
!pip install python-docx
import docx

source_file = 'textbox.docx'
doc = docx.Document(source_file)

text = [];
for table in doc.tables:
  for row in table.rows:
    for cell in row.cells:
      text.append(cell.text)
text
```

The result is the same (no text was extracted):

```
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

No support for textbox with python-docx.
However you can extract with win32com

You would look for shapes in the Doc and then check the `type` for `Textbox`, its numeric is 17. Then just print out the text per the first part of the code. However in your word example the text box is grouped so in this case the shape object has a numeric of 6 and we need to loop through the group of items to find the textbox again, type 17 and then we can extract the text.

Code sample

```
import win32com.client as win32

word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
source_file = 'textbox.docx'
doc = word.Documents.Open(source_file)

for sh in doc.Shapes:
    print(sh.Type)  # Type 17 is a textbox
    if sh.Type == 17:
        print(sh.Name)
        print(sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
    elif sh.Type == 6:  # 6 is a group
        for grp in sh.GroupItems:
            print(grp.Name)
            print(grp.Type)
            if grp.Type == 17:
                t = grp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                print(t.replace('\r', ''))
```

The output is; (text is truncated in this display)

```
Power Case Study: Solar PanelsMany households in Florida have adopted solar panels as a source of energy. There have been a total of 155,383 solar panel installations in Florida (
Yu et al. 2018), out of which 90.7% (140,265) are residential installations, and 9.3% (15118) are commercial installations. Over 90% of the solar panels have been installed since 
2017.Solar panels can provide access to continuous power supply when a hurricane damages the primary grid, as exemplified in Hurricane Ian by Babcock Ranch, a community located 12
 miles northeast of Fort Myers. 
...
```